# How to display an imageview from a url with holder

Tags: android, android-glide

to display the images on the Imageview from an url I use this code, but without success :

```
class Article(var id:Int,var nom:String,var lienimg:String, var ifram:String){
}

class ArticleAdapter (var articles:ArrayList<Article>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var vue=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.listeviss, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(vue)
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return articles.size
    }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        var article = articles.get(position)
        holder.nomvisite.setText(article.nom)
        holder.lieimgvisite.setText(article.lienimg)
        holder.ifram.setText(article.ifram)


        var urldelimg:String = "linkmysite.com/image.jpg"
        Glide.with(this).load(urldelimg).into(holder.imagedubloc)

    }

    class MyViewHolder(var vue:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(vue){
        var nomvisite=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nom_visitevirtuelle)
        var lieimgvisite=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lienimg)
        var ifram=vue.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.ifram)
        var imagedubloc=vue.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imagedubloc)

    }
```

i have this error :

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public open fun with(p0: Activity): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(p0: android.app.Fragment): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(p0: Context): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(p0: View): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(p0: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
public open fun with(p0: FragmentActivity): RequestManager defined in com.bumptech.glide.Glide
```

How can I fix this and display the image without error ? Thank You

Comment: Can you share the full code of the Adapter

Comment: @emkarachchi i just edit the code and add the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely where you've passed this to Glide.with(this) probably references the class and glide doesn't have a constructor that takes that, give it a view like Glide.with(holder.yourView) this is giving it a view which should fix it

Comment: actually i take this back but you do need a view or a context so maybe holder.ifram or holder.ifram.context

Comment: if i change Glide.with(this) with Glide.with(holder) i get a same error

Comment: Yh sorry I mentioned changing it to holder.yourView like holder.ifram.context for example

Comment: i test this : 
Glide.with(holder.imagedubloc.context).load(urldelimg).into(holder.imagedubloc)
app load but not image showing

Comment: Then there's something else wrong, what's the logs saying?

Comment: Can you share your image link?

Comment: logcat :
W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @ GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored

Comment: ahh its work :) can i do it in imagebutton ?

Comment: Yh course, looks like you.mighy be missing an annotation processor or your app glide module isn't set up correctly glad it's working though  can you accept my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I've achieved the same behavior using java.

When creating a new `Adapter` object, you need to pass the `Activity Context.`

```
myRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyAdapter(dataList,getActivity());
```

create a `Context` variable in your adapter class

`private final Context context;`

Then in the `constructor` of the `Adapter` class

```
public MyAdapter(List<MyData> dataSet, Context context)
{
    this.dataSet = dataSet;
    this.context = context; //this line should be added
}
```

Finally, you can load the image as follows.

`Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl).into(holder.imageView);`

Comment: you should avoid this where possible, its not completely bad but the less you pass around context the better, if you need a context get it from the view like for instance in  onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) you can get a context using parent.context

Comment: and using getActivity() should also be discouraged where possible as it can be null if called from a fragment again you can substitute this by using a view

Comment: @martinseal1987 I was doing this inside a fragment class. but I couldn't find it becoming `null`. But I wasn't aware of the `parent.context ` thing.

Thanks.

Comment: Yh I'm surprised the IDE isn't highlighting it to tell you this could be null

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  Glide.with(this), provide associated UI context in adapter's constructor and use like: Glide.with(context)

Comment: if i change Glide.with(this) to Glide.with(context) i get this error : Classifier 'Context' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here